# use Systemd on ASP.NET Core 6.0 and 7.0 and 8.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

if you want host your asp app on linux with systemd in **ASP.NET Core 5** : you must add `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd` nuget package with this configuration:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSystemd() <----------------------- HERE
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); 
                }) ;
        }
    }
```

but what about **ASP.NET Core 6.0 & 7.0 & 8.0**?

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be different for 6 and 7? Your code in the question works just fine for 6 and 7. In fact this is _the_ recommended method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in **ASP.NET Core 6.0 & 7.0 & 8.0**:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd;
//....
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSystemd();  <=-----------------------HERE
```

Comment: This! So many tutorials have a misleading line `builder.UseSystemd()`

Comment: Plus, as @gl3yn pointed out, for .net8 you need to reference `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd`

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that there seems to be a new way to do the same thing. (This also applies to creating windows services using `UseWindowsService` and possibly other methods.)

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61634#issuecomment-1133277946) they have added a new extension method to `IServiceCollection` but it is named `AddSystemd()` to align it with the other extension methods on that interface.

My googling is failing to find the relevant github page for the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.SystemdHostBuilderExtensions` class but here is the code according to VS2022:

```
    public static IHostBuilder UseSystemd(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(hostBuilder);

        if (SystemdHelpers.IsSystemdService())
        {
            hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                AddSystemdLifetime(services);
            });
        }
        return hostBuilder;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddSystemd(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(services);

        if (SystemdHelpers.IsSystemdService())
        {
            AddSystemdLifetime(services);
        }
        return services;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This allows systemd to be used with `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()`, which returns a `HostApplicationBuilder` instead of an `IHostBuilder` and therefore doesn't have access to the standard `.UseSystemd()` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

in **.NET 8**, you need to install the nuget package **Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd**;

and in your *Program.cs* you need to add

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); // <- already there by default

builder.Host.UseSystemd();
// etcetera
// builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();
// builder.WebHost.UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
// builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(...);
```

Comment: This is already covered in OP's self-answer.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, in .NET 8 you don't have `CreateHostBuilder`, I'll make my answer more complete

Comment: Yes, OP's answer already has that second line, too.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 8, this has become

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    
    HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

    
    builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "CorPdfHealthMonitor";
    });
    
    builder.Services.AddSystemd();
    // etc. 
    // e.g.  
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

    IHost host = builder.Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
        
    return await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
} // End Task Main
```