# Error when trying to user "UseSystemd" with net.core 6.0 linux service

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, service

I'm following this tutorial: https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-running-applications-as-linux-service/ to make a simple linux net core service (using net core 6.0).

The difference that i'm using visual studio in Windows to program. When i start a worker template and type ".UseSystemd()" in Program Class, the error appears:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 
'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost'. An 
explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    RpiService  E:\OneDrive - Hy 
Brazil Energia S.A\Hy Brazil\WebServices\RpiService\RpiService\RpiService\Program.cs     
3   Active
```

The Program Class Code:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSystemd();
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext,services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

I downloaded the tutorial source code, and open with visual studio and the error doesn't appear. Any one knows what the difference start template in Linux or Windows?

I read the post [use Systemd on ASP.NET Core 6.0 and 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233335/use-systemd-on-asp-net-core-6-0-and-7-0), but my appication doesn't are WebApplication, i can't use this context and i don't know how adapt this code to console application.